# Spritekit is a SKSpriteNode facing another SKSpriteNode

Tags: rotation, sprite-kit, direction

I'd like to find out if a sprite is facing another sprite? For instance I would like to make a player have the ability to shoot a monster if he is pointing his gun anywhere between the length of the monster. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if the player node is facing the enemy node, you will need to calculate the angle between the nodes (see angle theta in Figure 1).

[image]

**Figure 1** Diagram showing the angles between the nodes in the scene

Calculate theta by taking the inverse tangent of the difference in y divided by the difference in x:

```
    CGFloat dx = enemy.position.x - player.position.x;
    CGFloat dy = enemy.position.y - player.position.y;

    theta = atan2f(dy, dx);
```

If the difference between theta and the player's zRotation is small, the player is facing the enemy.

```
   if (fabs(theta-player.zRotation) < maxDifference) {
        // Do something here
   }
```

Comment: Please email me when you have a chance. My address is on my profile page.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! Only thing I was missing was returning the absolute between the two...

Answer (score 0):

```
if((isPlayerFacingLeft == true) && (_player.position.x > enemy.position.x))
{
    // player is on right of object and facing towards object
}

if((isPlayerFacingLeft == false) && (_player.position.x < enemy.position.x))
{
    // player is on left of object and facing towards object
}
```

Comment: That would work however the player is controlled by a joystick and is able to rotate 360 degrees, not just up down left or right. I should have mentioned this in my original question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user1351956 - Then take the absolute result from subtracting 180 from either the player's or enemy's zRotation, compare both angles and set an acceptable margin for view. Something like 20 perhaps. The rest is the pretty much the code above.